# moving *.tpl into "templates" folder, but Drupal does not recognize them. How?

Tags: 7, theming

I am building a custom theme. Currently, I put all the overridden *.tpl files under the theme root folder; it would be more clean and meaningful to put those files under "mytheme/templates", but Drupal does not recognize them after I move them. (I did clear the cache.)

Did I miss any steps?

Comment: Did you clear all the cache? How did you do that?

Comment: drush cache-clear all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also run into a situation where I had to create a **page.tpl.php** file before Drupal would recognize other **page--foo.tpl.php** files.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that is only the case in Drupal 6. Drupal 7 should be able to discover node--article.tpl.php without having to create node.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the new template suggestions with two hyphens instead of one ?

For instance, **page-front.tpl.php** becomes **page--front.tpl.php** in D7

More on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Comment: yes, i am using the new template suggestion convention. like I said, if I put tpl under **sites/all/themes/mytheme**, it works, but if I moved then to **sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates**, then clear all cache, re-enable mytheme, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a copy of Bartik Theme named Vartik.

In the templates folder I have the original page.tpl.php and I have created a page--node--add--CONTENT_TYPE_ID.tpl.php and it works.

Try it!